# Python re.search get value

Tags: python

I need to get the value of this regular expression

"show_suggested_profiles":false

This is my code:

```
re.search('show_suggested_profiles',r).group()
```

Output:

```
show_suggested_profiles
```

Expected result output:

```
false
```

Comment: Why you use `.group()`? If there is a match `re.search` will return a match object, otherwise it will return None.

Comment: This works for example: followers = re.search('"edge_followed_by":{"count":([0-9]+)}',r).group(1)

Comment: This returns to me the exact value of followers number

Comment: Expression:  "edge_followed_by":{"count":193314}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you want is a capturing group:

`re.search('"show_suggested_profiles"\s*:\s*([^\s]*)',r).group(1)`

This will match `"show_suggested_profiles":anything` where `anything` is captured as first group (basically the part of the regulare expression that is within the first set of brackets). I added `\s*` around the `:` so it gets a bit more tolerant. Probably the minimal use case would be
`re.search('"show_suggested_profiles":(true|false)',r).group(1)`
where only `true`or `false`are getting matched as part of the group 1.

Comment: what if i have a string that ends with: **","** For example if the expression was :   **"show_suggested_profiles":scascadakjkjadbkaudusadhuadsiids,**

Comment: if you have a comma, after your true or false you can expand the re by adding "," at the end. e.g. re.search('"show_suggested_profiles":(true|false),',r)

Comment: the important point is that everything gets matched but only the part in round brackets will be captured as group 1. So expanding on the regulare expression a bit by adding `\s*` (there can be zero or more white spaces) and `,?` you can match a bit more tolerant:   `'"show_suggested_profiles":(true|false)\s*,?'`

Comment: this is another example, separeted by the other one

Comment: I would suggest that you do a regular expression with two capturing groups:
`res=re.search('"([^"]+":([^,]*),?',r)`, then  `argument = res.group(1)` and `value=res.group(2)` the important part here is that `([^,]*)` collects everything that is not a comma into a group (two in the "advanced" example)

Comment: can your value contain commas?